# Available d-bus java implementations

Tags: java, dbus

We are developing a piece of software that does it's IPC over D-Bus.  However, we're running into a lot of tiny problems with the java 'dbuslib' reference implementation from freedesktop.org.

Is that a surprise to you?  I'm actually looking for alternatives: I don't seem to stumble onto any other implementation.

Do you know of any (industry-grade stability) java d-bus implementations?

Comment: I don't know a lot about D-Bus, but it's not a suprise, because (unfortunately) the relationship between the open-source desktop community and Java has been ... less than ideal.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: politics... I don't get them :)

Comment: in this case there are two separate causes: One *big* problem was the license of Java for a long time (now it's very open-source friendly, but it wasn't always this way) and the other one is the perceived slowness/resource hunger of Java for Desktop application.

Comment: Did you try reporting the problems and see if the authors/maintainers react? Sometimes a less-than-perfect library with active developers is better than a almost-perfect library where no one responds.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: I just did, my colleague did so two months ago.  The latest release dates back from 2009, and my bug report was already present since then, too (assigned, yet not fixed yet)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a classical "unloved" project where the key developers have lost interest / enthusiasm.  Submitting bug reports / issues is a waste of time if they are not being addressed.

I think the solution is to develop your own fixes and submit them as patches.  Then, if your patches are not integrated in a timely fashion, ask for commit rights.

Even if you get no assistance from the erstwhile developers, the patches will fix the problems for you.

---

And no, I couldn't find any alternative libraries either.

---

And here's an article that is (IMO) pertinent to your situation:

http://www.networkworld.com/news/2011/083011-zemlin-250234.html

(Jim Zemlin is focussed on Linux, but what he is saying clearly applies to all open source software.)